# Find number in a reply returned via serial

Tags: serial, esp8266, string

I am communicating with my GoPro via ESP8266 and GET requests.
One of the replies returns a set of predefined number and what I would like to do is extract the number on position "38". This is what the reply looks like in full:

```
SEND OK

+IPD,4,163:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 24 Apr 2016 03:13:40 GMT
Server: Cherokee/1.2.101b150714_bd80061 (UNIX)
Content-type: application/json


OK

+IPD,4,972:3c0
{"status":{
"1":1,"2":1,"3":0,"4":0,"6":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"13":0,"14":0,"15":0,"16":0,"17":1,"19":0,"20":0,"21":0,"22":0,"23":0,"24":0,"26":0,"27":0,"28":18,"29":"","30":"xxx","31":0,"32":0,"33":0,"34":7933,"35":5039,"36":0,"37":4,"38":0,"39":4,"40":"%10%04%18%03%0D%28","41":0,"42":0,"43":1,"44":0,"45":0,"46":0,"47":0,"48":0,"49":0,"54":29698976,"55":1,"56":4,"57":1022279,"58":0,"59":0,"60":500,"61":2,"62":0,"63":0,"64":0},
"settings":{"1":0,"2":9,"3":6,"4":1,"5":2,"6":1,"7":1,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":1,"12":1,"13":1,"14":0,"15":4,"16":0,"17":2,"18":2,"19":2,"20":0,"21":1,"22":2,"23":0,"24":2,"25":0,"26":4,"27":0,"28":2,"29":1,"30":10,"31":0,"32":0,"33":0,"34":1,"35":2,"36":1,"37":2,"38":0,"39":4,"40":0,"41":13,"42":8,"43":0,"44":8,"45":8,"46":0,"47":0,"48":0,"49":0,"50":1,"51":1,"52":0,"53":0,"54":0,"55":1,"56":1,"57":1,"58":1,"59":0,"60":8,"61":1,"62":700000,"63":4,"64":1,"65":0,"66":0,"67":0,"68":0,"69":0,"70":0,"71":0,"72":1}}

0


OK
```

As you can see, position 38=0 (...,"38":0,...). The number 0 will increment. So I would like to find the string `"38":` and do something with following numbers until `,`.
What is the correct way to grab that number from the serial reply and echo or do something with it?

Comment: Are you using an Arduino to see the serial reply ? Or are you directly connected to the ESP8266 via USB?

Comment: USB <-> Teensy <-> ESP ~~~~ GoPro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are being returned JSON, you can use the jsoncpp library found [here](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)
To split your return to an array. Then you simply retrieve whatever item you want using array index notation.

Here is another helpful post on creating arrays of strings in C++ from JSON.
[C++ and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082643/parsing-json-arrays-in-c)

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson and Serial.find();